# on SelectedIndexChanged ListItem in checkboxList are duplicated

Tags: c#, asp.net

Each time on SelectedIndexChanged a new ListItem is created in checkboxList. I need to display only the listItem which is selected form the dropdown list.

```
 protected void ddlgrade_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string gradeid = ddlgrade.SelectedValue;
    
                if (Convert.ToInt32(gradeid) != -1 )
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT t.subject_name,t.subject_id from tblsubject t where NOT EXISTS(SELECT sg.subject_id from tblsubject_grade sg where t.subject_id = sg.subject_id and sg.grade_id = @g_Name)";
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g_Name", gradeid);
                    SqlDataReader dr;
                    con.Open();
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        ListItem item = new ListItem();
                        item.Text = dr["subject_name"].ToString();
                        item.Value = dr["subject_id"].ToString();
                        CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(item);
                    }
                }
```

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlXJR.png)
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByAgB.png)

Comment: You should do `CheckBoxList1.Items.Clear();` before while loop

Comment: Yes its working. Thanks :)

Comment: I removed the sql-server tag, as that doesn't seem to be relevant here.